# How can I use flexbox to properly position the buttons of my calculator?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I use flexbox to arrange the buttons of my calculator, which are created with div elements?

I have designed a calculator exactly like the Windows 10 calculator, but the problem is that its buttons are not arranged properly . I want to use flexbox to arrange my buttons. How can I solve this issue using flexbox or CSS?

My HTML and CSS code:

```css
::selection{
    background: transparent;
  }
  
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body{

    font: 1rem 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: #e9e9e9;

}

.all-aitem{

    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    /* min-height: 400px; */
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 3fr minmax(250px, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 45px 2fr 4fr ;
    grid-template-areas: 
    'header header'
    'row-up  history'
    'button  history';
}

.header{
    
    grid-area: header;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 25px;
}

.text-header{

    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 10px;
    margin-left: 1px;

}

.icon-header{

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.icon-close:hover{

    background-color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
    
}

.icon-restor:hover{

    background-color: darkgrey;
    cursor: pointer;

}

.icon-minimize:hover{
    
    background-color: darkgrey;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.row-up{

    grid-area: row-up;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.left-3-item{

    display: flex;
    margin-left: 1px;
    gap: 5px;
}


.icon-bar:hover{

    background-color: #D3D3D3; 
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    
}

.text-left{

    font-size:20px;
    font-weight: 500;

}

.icon-keep:hover{

    background-color: #D3D3D3; 
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    
}

.zero{

    font-size: 50px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    text-align: end;
    font-weight: bold;
     margin-right: 30px;
    
}

.memory-btn{

    display: flex;
    
}

.memory{

    font-size: 15px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 45px;
    width: max(50px,10%);
}

.memory1{
      
    font-size: 15px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-weight: 500;
    height: 45px;
    width: max(50px,10%);

}

.memory:hover{

    background-color:#D3D3D3; 
    
}

.button{

    grid-area: button;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between; 
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
   
    
    

}

.number{


    width: 19.8%;
    height: 19.6%;
    background-color:#fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.number:hover{
    background-color:#F8F8FF;
}

.sign{

    width: 19.8%;
    height: 19.6%;
    background-color:#DCDCDC;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 4px;
   
}

.sign:hover{

    background-color:#D3D3D3;
}

.history{

    grid-area: history;
    margin-top: 5px;

}

.left-text{
    
    display: flex;
    gap: 15px;
}

.his-btn{

    border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(228, 137, 19);
     cursor: pointer;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <div class="all-aitem">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="text-header">Calculator</div>
            <div class="icon-header">
                <div class="icon-close  icon-header-left">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="20" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" width="48"><path d="m249-207-42-42 231-231-231-231 42-42 231 231 231-231 42 42-231 231 231 231-42 42-231-231-231 231Z"/></svg>
                </div>
    
                <div class="icon-restor  icon-header-left">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="20" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" width="48"><path d="M180-120q-24 0-42-18t-18-42v-600q0-24 18-42t42-18h600q24 0 42 18t18 42v600q0 24-18 42t-42 18H180Zm0-60h600v-600H180v600Z"/></svg>
                </div>
    
                <div class="icon-minimize  icon-header-left">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="20" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" width="48"><path d="M200-450v-60h560v60H200Z"/></svg>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="row-up">
            <div class="left-3-item">
                <div class="icon-bar">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="25" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" width="40"><path d="M140-269.231v-33.846h680v33.846H140Zm0-193.846v-33.846h680v33.846H140Zm0-193.846v-33.846h680v33.846H140Z"/></svg>
                </div>
    
                <p class="text-left">
                    Standard
                </p>
    
                <div class="icon-keep">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="21" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" width="40"><path d="M178.461-200q-24.577 0-41.519-16.942Q120-233.884 120-258.461v-252.308h33.846v252.308q0 10.769 6.923 17.692t17.692 6.923h603.078q10.769 0 17.692-6.923t6.923-17.692v-443.078q0-10.769-6.923-17.692t-17.692-6.923H449.231V-760h332.308q24.577 0 41.519 16.942Q840-726.116 840-701.539v443.078q0 24.577-16.942 41.519Q806.116-200 781.539-200H178.461Zm516.437-120 24.333-24.333-180.718-179.718H675.18v-33.846H481.333v193.846h33.847v-135.667L694.898-320ZM120-600v-160h240v160H120Zm360 120Z"/></svg>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p class="zero">0</p>
            <div class="memory-btn">
                <div class="memory1" style="color: rgb(167, 174, 175);">MC</div>
                <div class="memory1" style="color: rgb(167, 174, 175);">MR</div>
                <div class="memory">M+</div>
                <div class="memory">M-</div>
                <div class="memory">MS</div>
            
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="button">
                <div class="num1 sign">%</div>
                <div class="num2 sign">CE</div>
                <div class="num3 sign">C</div>
                <div class="num4 sign"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="20" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" width="40"><path d="m439.897-349.641 106.257-106.256L652.41-349.641l24.77-24.256L570.257-480l106.102-106.103-24.256-24.256-105.949 106.256-106.257-106.256-24.256 24.256L522.051-480l-106.41 106.103 24.256 24.256ZM164.615-480l141.949-200.821q12.846-18.359 31.902-28.769Q357.523-720 380.034-720h356.889q23.911 0 41.186 17.275 17.276 17.276 17.276 41.186v363.078q0 23.91-17.276 41.186Q760.834-240 736.923-240H380q-22.616 0-41.218-11.179-18.603-11.18-32.218-29.539L164.615-480Zm41.641 0L338.38-293.846q6.153 8.462 16.538 14.231 10.384 5.769 21.923 5.769h360.082q9.231 0 16.923-7.692 7.693-7.692 7.693-16.923v-363.078q0-9.231-7.693-16.923-7.692-7.692-16.923-7.692H376.769q-11.538 0-21.923 5.769-10.385 5.769-16.538 14.231L206.256-480Zm555.283 0v-206.154 412.308V-480Z"/></svg></div>
                <div class="num5 sign">&#247;</div>

                <div class="num6 sign"><img
                    class="radical"
                    style="width: 20px;"
                    src="data:image/png;base64,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"
                    alt=""
                  /></div>
                <div class="num7 number">7</div>
                <div class="num8 number">8</div>
                <div class="num9 number">9</div>
                <div class="num10 sign">&#215;</div>

                <div class="num11 sign">x<sup>2</sup></div>
                <div class="num12 number">4</div>
                <div class="num13 number">5</div>
                <div class="num14 number">6</div>
                <div class="num15 sign">&#8722;</div>

                <div class="num16 sign">x<sup>3</sup></div>
                <div class="num17 number">1</div>
                <div class="num18 number">2</div>
                <div class="num19 number">3</div>
                <div class="num20 sign">&#43;</div>

                <div class="num21 sign">1/x</div>
                <div class="num22 sign">+/-</div>
                <div class="num23 number">0</div>
                <div class="num24 sign">&#8729;</div>
                <div class="num25 sign">&#61;</div>

            </div>
            <div class="history">
                <div class="left-text">
                  <h4 class="his-btn">History</h4>
                  <h4 class="mem-btn">Memory</h4>
                </div>
                <p style=" margin-top: 40px;">There's no history yet</p>
            </div>
    </div>

    <script src="calicator1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Frankly, flexbox is not the optimal method here. Css-grid is much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using grid instead of flexbox here. So for the button class, replace display: flexbox to display: grid, and add a four column grid layout to the button class. And finally remove the width and height properties on the number and sign classes. Also remove the justify-content, align-items and justify content properties on the button element. Hope this helps

```
.button{
    grid-area: button;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

.number{
    background-color:#fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.number:hover{
    background-color:#F8F8FF;
}

.sign{
    background-color:#DCDCDC;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 4px;
   
}

.sign:hover{

    background-color:#D3D3D3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I changed your displays to use grids.

- added a class to the container for the buttons
- changed the CSS to target this class
- added a new class to each "button" within that container and used that to style them all.
- Note the `display: grid; place-items: center;` on the "buttons" super centers the content in each.
- I put in ugly borders just to show what is where; they can be removed perhaps.
- I removed quite a bit of the CSS with that consolidation

```css
    .button-container {
      grid-area: button;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 3em);
      grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 3em);
      gap: 0.25em;
      border-color: #00FFFF;
      font-size: 1.5em;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .calc-item {
      justify-self: center;
      width: 3em;
      height: 3em;
      border: 1px solid #FFFF00;
      display: block;
      display: grid;
      place-items: center;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
```

Things display kind of weird below a certain page size but that was not the question.

```css
::selection {
  background: transparent;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  font: 1rem 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.all-aitem {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr minmax(250px, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 45px 2fr 4fr;
  grid-template-areas: 'header header' 'row-up  history' 'button  history';
}

.all-aitem>* {
  border: dashed 2px #ff00ff;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 25px;
}

.row-up {
  grid-area: row-up;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.history {
  grid-area: history;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.button-container {
  grid-area: button;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 3em);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 3em);
  gap: 0.25em;
  border-color: #00FFFF;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  align-items: center;
}

.calc-item {
  justify-self: center;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  border: 1px solid #FFFF00;
  display: block;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.number {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.number:hover {
  background-color: #F8F8FF;
}

.sign {
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sign:hover {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
}

.text-header {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 3px 3px 3px 10px;
  margin-left: 1px;
}

.icon-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.icon-close:hover {
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.icon-restor:hover {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.icon-minimize:hover {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.left-3-item {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 1px;
  gap: 5px;
}

.icon-bar:hover {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.text-left {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.icon-keep:hover {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.zero {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  text-align: end;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.memory-btn {
  display: flex;
}

.memory {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 45px;
  width: max(50px, 10%);
}

.memory1 {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  height: 45px;
  width: max(50px, 10%);
}

.memory:hover {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
}

.left-text {
  display: flex;
  gap: 15px;
}

.his-btn {
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(228, 137, 19);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="all-aitem">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="text-header">Calculator</div>
    <div class="icon-header">
      <div class="icon-close  icon-header-left">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="20" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" width="48"><path d="m249-207-42-42 231-231-231-231 42-42 231 231 231-231 42 42-231 231 231 231-42 42-231-231-231 231Z"/></svg>
      </div>
      <div class="icon-restor  icon-header-left">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="20" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" width="48"><path d="M180-120q-24 0-42-18t-18-42v-600q0-24 18-42t42-18h600q24 0 42 18t18 42v600q0 24-18 42t-42 18H180Zm0-60h600v-600H180v600Z"/></svg>
      </div>
      <div class="icon-minimize  icon-header-left">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="20" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" width="48"><path d="M200-450v-60h560v60H200Z"/></svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-up">
    <div class="left-3-item">
      <div class="icon-bar">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="25" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" width="40"><path d="M140-269.231v-33.846h680v33.846H140Zm0-193.846v-33.846h680v33.846H140Zm0-193.846v-33.846h680v33.846H140Z"/></svg>
      </div>
      <p class="text-left">
        Standard
      </p>
      <div class="icon-keep">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="21" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" width="40"><path d="M178.461-200q-24.577 0-41.519-16.942Q120-233.884 120-258.461v-252.308h33.846v252.308q0 10.769 6.923 17.692t17.692 6.923h603.078q10.769 0 17.692-6.923t6.923-17.692v-443.078q0-10.769-6.923-17.692t-17.692-6.923H449.231V-760h332.308q24.577 0 41.519 16.942Q840-726.116 840-701.539v443.078q0 24.577-16.942 41.519Q806.116-200 781.539-200H178.461Zm516.437-120 24.333-24.333-180.718-179.718H675.18v-33.846H481.333v193.846h33.847v-135.667L694.898-320ZM120-600v-160h240v160H120Zm360 120Z"/></svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="zero">0</p>
    <div class="memory-btn">
      <div class="memory1" style="color: rgb(167, 174, 175);">MC</div>
      <div class="memory1" style="color: rgb(167, 174, 175);">MR</div>
      <div class="memory">M+</div>
      <div class="memory">M-</div>
      <div class="memory">MS</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="button-container">
    <div class="num1 sign calc-item">%</div>
    <div class="num2 sign calc-item">CE</div>
    <div class="num3 sign calc-item">C</div>
    <div class="num4 sign calc-item"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="20" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" width="40"><path d="m439.897-349.641 106.257-106.256L652.41-349.641l24.77-24.256L570.257-480l106.102-106.103-24.256-24.256-105.949 106.256-106.257-106.256-24.256 24.256L522.051-480l-106.41 106.103 24.256 24.256ZM164.615-480l141.949-200.821q12.846-18.359 31.902-28.769Q357.523-720 380.034-720h356.889q23.911 0 41.186 17.275 17.276 17.276 17.276 41.186v363.078q0 23.91-17.276 41.186Q760.834-240 736.923-240H380q-22.616 0-41.218-11.179-18.603-11.18-32.218-29.539L164.615-480Zm41.641 0L338.38-293.846q6.153 8.462 16.538 14.231 10.384 5.769 21.923 5.769h360.082q9.231 0 16.923-7.692 7.693-7.692 7.693-16.923v-363.078q0-9.231-7.693-16.923-7.692-7.692-16.923-7.692H376.769q-11.538 0-21.923 5.769-10.385 5.769-16.538 14.231L206.256-480Zm555.283 0v-206.154 412.308V-480Z"/></svg></div>
    <div class="num5 sign calc-item">&#247;</div>
    <div class="num6 sign calc-item"><img class="radical" style="width: 20px;" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
        alt="" /></div>
    <div class="num7 number calc-item">7</div>
    <div class="num8 number calc-item">8</div>
    <div class="num9 number calc-item">9</div>
    <div class="num10 sign calc-item">&#215;</div>
    <div class="num11 sign calc-item">x<sup>2</sup></div>
    <div class="num12 number calc-item">4</div>
    <div class="num13 number calc-item">5</div>
    <div class="num14 number calc-item">6</div>
    <div class="num15 sign calc-item">&#8722;</div>

    <div class="num16 sign calc-item">x<sup>3</sup></div>
    <div class="num17 number calc-item">1</div>
    <div class="num18 number calc-item">2</div>
    <div class="num19 number calc-item">3</div>
    <div class="num20 sign calc-item">&#43;</div>

    <div class="num21 sign calc-item">1/x</div>
    <div class="num22 sign calc-item">+/-</div>
    <div class="num23 number calc-item">0</div>
    <div class="num24 sign calc-item">&#8729;</div>
    <div class="num25 sign calc-item">&#61;</div>
  </div>
  <div class="history">
    <div class="left-text">
      <h4 class="his-btn">History</h4>
      <h4 class="mem-btn">Memory</h4>
    </div>
    <p style=" margin-top: 40px;">There's no history yet</p>
  </div>
</div>
```